# android SlidingTab start activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I have 3 Tabs (Slidingtablayout). The left tab has a fragment and the right tab has a fragment.

**But the tab in the middle should start a new activity and not have a fragment.
Is this possible and how can i do this?**

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

MyPageAdapter pagerAdapter;
List<Fragment> fragments;
ViewPager viewPager;
SlidingTabLayout tabLayout;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // initializing SlidiTabLayout
    tabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

    // Customizing SlidingTabLayout
    tabLayout.setCustomTabView(R.layout.custom_tab, 0);
    tabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);

    // initializing PagerAdapter
    fragments = getFragments();
    pagerAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments, this);

    // initializing ViewPager
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);


    tabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);

}
    // adding fagments 
    public List<Fragment> getFragments() {
    List<Fragment> addFragment = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    addFragment.add(ExampleFragment.newInstance());
    // Activity instead of fragment 
    addFragment.add(Change this .newInstance());
    addFragment.add(ExampleFragment.newInstance());

    return addFragment;
}
```

[image]

**MyPagerAdapter**

```
public class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private final List<Fragment> fragments;
private CharSequence Titles[];
private Context context;

int icons [] = {R.drawable.lefticon, R.drawable.middleicon, R.drawable.righticon};
Drawable drawable;

public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments, Context context) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(icons[position]);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
    SpannableString sb = new SpannableString(" ");
    ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(drawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
    sb.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return sb;
}
// this.fragments.get(position)
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return this.fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}


}
```

**How the fragments look like:**

```
public class PlayFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "EXTRA_MESSAGE";

public static final ExampleFragment newInstance()
{
    PlayFragment mf = new PlayFragment();
    Bundle bd = new Bundle(1);
    mf.setArguments(bd);
    return mf;
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);
    return v;
}
}
```

**SlidingTabLayout**

```
public class SlidingTabLayout extends HorizontalScrollView {
/**
 * Allows complete control over the colors drawn in the tab layout. Set with
 * {@link #setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer)}.
 */
public interface TabColorizer {

    /**
     * @return return the color of the indicator used when {@code position} is selected.
     */
    int getIndicatorColor(int position);

}

private static final int TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS = 24;
private static final int TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS = 16;
private static final int TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP = 12;

private int mTitleOffset;

private int mTabViewLayoutId;
private int mTabViewTextViewId;
private boolean mDistributeEvenly;

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private SparseArray<String> mContentDescriptions = new SparseArray<String>();
private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mViewPagerPageChangeListener;

private final SlidingTabStrip mTabStrip;

public SlidingTabLayout(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    // Disable the Scroll Bar
    setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    // Make sure that the Tab Strips fills this View
    setFillViewport(true);

    mTitleOffset = (int) (TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

    mTabStrip = new SlidingTabStrip(context);
    addView(mTabStrip, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}

/**
 * Set the custom {@link TabColorizer} to be used.
 *
 * If you only require simple custmisation then you can use
 * {@link #setSelectedIndicatorColors(int...)} to achieve
 * similar effects.
 */
public void setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer tabColorizer) {
    mTabStrip.setCustomTabColorizer(tabColorizer);
}

public void setDistributeEvenly(boolean distributeEvenly) {
    mDistributeEvenly = distributeEvenly;
}

/**
 * Sets the colors to be used for indicating the selected tab. These colors are treated as a
 * circular array. Providing one color will mean that all tabs are indicated with the same color.
 */
public void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
    mTabStrip.setSelectedIndicatorColors(colors);
}

/**
 * Set the {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener}. When using {@link SlidingTabLayout} you are
 * required to set any {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener} through this method. This is so
 * that the layout can update it's scroll position correctly.
 *
 * @see ViewPager#setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)
 */
public void setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener) {
    mViewPagerPageChangeListener = listener;
}

/**
 * Set the custom layout to be inflated for the tab views.
 *
 * @param layoutResId Layout id to be inflated
 * @param textViewId id of the {@link TextView} in the inflated view
 */
public void setCustomTabView(int layoutResId, int textViewId) {
    mTabViewLayoutId = layoutResId;
    mTabViewTextViewId = textViewId;
}

/**
 * Sets the associated view pager. Note that the assumption here is that the pager content
 * (number of tabs and tab titles) does not change after this call has been made.
 */
public void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    mTabStrip.removeAllViews();

    mViewPager = viewPager;
    if (viewPager != null) {
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new InternalViewPagerListener());
        populateTabStrip();
    }
}

/**
 * Create a default view to be used for tabs. This is called if a custom tab view is not set via
 * {@link #setCustomTabView(int, int)}.
 */
protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
    textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
    getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground,
            outValue, true);
    textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
    textView.setAllCaps(true);

    int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

    return textView;
}

private void populateTabStrip() {
    final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
    final View.OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();
        // adapter.getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View tabView = null;
        TextView tabTitleView = null;

        if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0) {
            // If there is a custom tab view layout id set, try and inflate it
            tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip,
                    false);
            tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);
        }

        if (tabView == null) {
            tabView = createDefaultTabView(getContext());
        }

        if (tabTitleView == null && TextView.class.isInstance(tabView)) {
            tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView;
        }

        if (mDistributeEvenly) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tabView.getLayoutParams();
            lp.width = 0;
            lp.weight = 1;
        }

        tabTitleView.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));
        tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);
        String desc = mContentDescriptions.get(i, null);
        if (desc != null) {
            tabView.setContentDescription(desc);
        }

        mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
        if (i == mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
            tabView.setSelected(true);
        }
    }
}

public void setContentDescription(int i, String desc) {
    mContentDescriptions.put(i, desc);
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    if (mViewPager != null) {
        scrollToTab(mViewPager.getCurrentItem(), 0);
    }
}

private void scrollToTab(int tabIndex, int positionOffset) {
    final int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
    if (tabStripChildCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0 || tabIndex >= tabStripChildCount) {
        return;
    }

    View selectedChild = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex);
    if (selectedChild != null) {
        int targetScrollX = selectedChild.getLeft() + positionOffset;

        if (tabIndex > 0 || positionOffset > 0) {
            // If we're not at the first child and are mid-scroll, make sure we obey the offset
            targetScrollX -= mTitleOffset;
        }

        scrollTo(targetScrollX, 0);
    }
}

private class InternalViewPagerListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private int mScrollState;

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
        if ((tabStripChildCount == 0) || (position < 0) || (position >= tabStripChildCount)) {
            return;
        }

        mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, positionOffset);

        View selectedTitle = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position);
        int extraOffset = (selectedTitle != null)
                ? (int) (positionOffset * selectedTitle.getWidth())
                : 0;
        scrollToTab(position, extraOffset);

        if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
            mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset,
                    positionOffsetPixels);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        mScrollState = state;

        if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
            mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, 0f);
            scrollToTab(position, 0);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
            mTabStrip.getChildAt(i).setSelected(position == i);
        }
        if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
            mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
        }
    }

}

private class TabClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if (v == mTabStrip.getChildAt(i)) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

And i tried something too. Because i want to have:

- 3 Tabs
- 2 Fragments
- Tab in the middle should be without fragment

I edited this method here (MainActivity):

```
    // adding fragments 
    public List<Fragment> getFragments() {
    List<Fragment> addFragment = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    addFragment.add(ExampleFragment.newInstance());
    delete middle fragment
    //addFragment.add(ExampleFragment.newInstance());

    addFragment.add(ExampleFragment.newInstance());

    return addFragment;
}
```

I deleted one Fragment.

Which means i accomplished the goal to have 2 Fragments.

- 2 Fragments *check*

Because i only have as much tabs as fragments, that would mean that i'd only have 2 Tabs too.

So i went to the SlidingTabLayout and changed this method:

I changed the for loop to this |i < 3| instead of |i < adapter.getCount();|

```
    private void populateTabStrip() {
    final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
    final View.OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();
        // 3 instead of adapter.getCount(); | For 3 tabs
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        View tabView = null;
        TextView tabTitleView = null;

        if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0) {
            // If there is a custom tab view layout id set, try and inflate it
            tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip,
                    false);
            tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);
        }

        if (tabView == null) {
            tabView = createDefaultTabView(getContext());
        }

        if (tabTitleView == null && TextView.class.isInstance(tabView)) {
            tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView;
        }

        if (mDistributeEvenly) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tabView.getLayoutParams();
            lp.width = 0;
            lp.weight = 1;
        }

        tabTitleView.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));
        tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);
        String desc = mContentDescriptions.get(i, null);
        if (desc != null) {
            tabView.setContentDescription(desc);
        }

        mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
        if (i == mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
            tabView.setSelected(true);
        }
    }
}
```

And Now:

- 3 Tabs *check*

and

- 2 SlidingTablayout *check*

but not

- Tab in the middle should be without fragment

I had 3 Fragments and 3 Tabs i deleted one Fragment and this caused that the last fragment moved one position up. Now the right fragment is in the position of the middle fragment. Now when i click on the middle tab i get the fragment which was on the right tab.

**In this case my question is how to get the fragment which moved now in the position of the middle tab back to the right tab.**

Hope you understand what i want. Sorry for my bad english :).

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, You NEED those fragments to Navigate between 3 tabs. So my solution is, since you need to launch an activity from 2nd Tab, Use 3 fragment. Yes 3 fragments, so use this code in the `onResume()` method of the Middle fragment:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

This should take you to a new activity.

Secondly, launching Activity for the 2nd Tab is a very bad design of your Application. I recommend not following this design if you are planning to release this application in the Play store. Use [Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) instead.

Comment: @xDerAhmed You can accept the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 4):

Create two fragment and one activity

Add activity to the tab as below

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;



    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SecondActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second").setIndicator("Second")
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Follow the link below to add activity to tabs.
http://www.technotalkative.com/android-tab-bar-example-1/